# In FFmpeg, encoding anything lower than slow preset takes video to level 5

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, x264, libx264

Why whenever I use any preset lower or equal to slow, it makes my video High@L5 (profile high / level 5)? It doesn't make sense to me, I always tought that levels were associeted with frame size, frame rate and data rate only

I've searched all over for a relation between presets and levels in x264 encoding through FFmpeg, but couldn't find any.

My only concern is compatibility, since anything above 4 tends to be exotic to most players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the increased number of reference frames. slow is 5, slower is 8 and and veryslow is 16. You can override by specifying a level directly, or set ref count to 4 or lower.